# Consulta sql en spring java

Tags: java, sql, crud

Estoy realizando un crud en spring de java, me falta la parte de consultar y necesito enviar los resultados a los setter de usuario, actualmente lo consulto en una lista y la retorno pero requiero enviar los datos de la consulta a lo setter de usuario -> usuario.setNombres(acadatodelacolumnanombre o posición de nombre en la db), como podría realizar esto ??

```
public List consultarUsuario(String id) {
        List consuList = null;
        try {
            consuList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("CALL ConsultarUsuario (?)", id);

        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return consuList;
    }
```

Comment: Puedes colocar tu implementación de la clase usuario por favor..

Comment: En la clase usuario solo están los get y set de nombres ,apellidos ,correo y clave no hay nada más, de resto de usuario tengo el dao con sus métodos

Comment: String nombres, apellidos , correo, clave;

public setNombres(nombres)
{ this.nombres = nombres;} 


public setApellidos(apellidos)
{ this.apellidos = apellidos;} 


public setCorreo(correo)
{ this.correo = correo;} 


public setClave(clave)
{ this.clave = clave;}

Comment: Tendrías que leer cada columna del resultado y hacer cada set a mano. Te recomendaría que uses GSon, que te permite con suma facilidad mapear un resultado a una clase directamente. Así, mediante una simple llamada las propiedades de tu clase se llenarían con los resultados y luego usarías los métodos get para mostrarlos.